# PDF image rendering in java swing

Tags: java, swing, pdf, jpedal

I am using JPedal free version jar to render PDF in my java swing program. The normal PDF is getting rendered properly but while rendering the PDF image(Image file converted to PDF file) the quality drops considerably(not readable at all).

[image: JPedal rendering Image PDF]

Example code :

```
public OpenViewer() {

    //create and initialise JPedal viewer component
    final Viewer myViewer =new Viewer();
    myViewer.setupViewer();

    //code to open when required
    final File file=null; //example is commented out below
    final InputStream stream = null;

    //open the stream or File
    try {
       file = new File("/Users/markee/Desktop/myfile.pdf"); // This PDF is converted from tiff 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    if(file!=null) {
        myViewer.executeCommand(Commands.OPENFILE, new Object[]{file});
    }



}
```

Comment: What is the preexisting code?

Comment: I am just setting the JPedal viewer in my InternalFrame and opening the PDF by pdf url .

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Does that happen for all PDF files with images our just for some?

Comment: This issue occurs for mostly all image files converted to PDF. In my case, i am using PDF which was converted from .tiff image

Comment: Have a look here http://files.idrsolutions.com/samplecode/org/jpedal/examples/images/ConvertPagesToHiResImages.java.html